# Program not entering sub-routine?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I am new to arduino/robotics and have written some simple code that should use interrupts to measure encoder ticks on wheels and stop once its reached a value (a set distance) however it doesn't seem to be incrementing the encoder value and thus the wheels never stop. Can someone assist me with this?
**code:**

```
const int pwm1 = 9 ;  //initializing pin 2 as pwm
const int in1 = 8 ;
const int in2 = 12 ;
const int pwm2 = 10 ;  //initializing pin 2 as pwm
const int in3 = 11 ;
const int in4 = 13 ;
const int e1 = 2 ;
const int e2 = 3 ;

const int tickGoal = 90;
volatile int encoderValue= 0; 

void isrFunction() {
  encoderValue++ ;
}

void setup() {
pinMode(in1,OUTPUT);
pinMode(in2,OUTPUT);
pinMode(in3,OUTPUT);
pinMode(in4,OUTPUT);
pinMode(pwm1,OUTPUT);
pinMode(pwm2,OUTPUT);
pinMode(e1, INPUT);
pinMode(e2, INPUT);
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(e1), isrFunction, CHANGE);
}

void loop() {
  if (encoderValue < tickGoal) {
    digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in2, HIGH);
    analogWrite(pwm1, 255);
    digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in4, HIGH);
    analogWrite(pwm2, 255);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in2, LOW);   
  }
}
```

Comment: pls note: I am using FALLING rather than CHANGE, and the comments are incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try turning on the internal pullup resistor for the interrupt pin.

`pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT_PULLUP);`

If that doesn't do it, run the canonical interrupt sketch and get the interrupt triggered to blink the LED:

```
int interruptPin = 2;
int LEDPin = 13;
volatile int state = LOW;

void setup() {
    pinMode(LEDPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(InterruptPin, INPUT_PULLUP)
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(InterruptPin), blink, CHANGE);
}

void loop() {
    digitalWrite(LEDPin, state);
}

void blink() {
    state = !state;
}
```

If this does not work, then you likely have a problem with your wiring or with the encoder, or the voltages, or a blown pin, or something like that. You can post more information if this doesn't get you there.